# Android thread bug

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask

I'm actually working on a chat android application.

I have a problem with a thread I created. Basically, my client application has an activity connected to a service. That service takes care of the communication between the client and the server. (I also use Asynctask for that)

I have two main scenarios:

- I send a request to the server (refresh friendlist, add a friend, signin...) and the response from the server is expected so no problem for this.
- The second scenario is about unexpected request from the server (when another person wants to communicate with you). For this, I created a thread in my service class like this.

  public void launchListener() {

  ```
          Runnable SocketListener = new Runnable(){

              public void run(){              
                  String msg = "";
                  String[] msg_parts = {"","",""};                
                  while(true){
                      try {
                          if (in.available() > 0){                            
                              msg = in.readLine();
                              msg_parts = msg.split(" ");                         
                              if (msg_parts[0].equals("CONNECTION")){
                                  Log.d("SocketService", "Broadcasting message");
                                  Intent intent = new Intent("ask.connection");
                                  intent.putExtra("nickname", msg_parts[1]);
                                  sendBroadcast(intent);
                              }
                          }
                      } catch (IOException e) {
                          e.printStackTrace();
                      }
                  }
              }
            };
            Thread t = new Thread(SocketListener);
            t.start();
      }
  ```

The problem is, that thread is only waiting for "connection", so it also intercept the expected response from the server and I don't know why but this thread freezes my application.
It's just a possibility, but maybe because I also use the **readLine** in another place, it doesn't work.

Here I use readLine for the expected response in Asyntask:

```
protected String doInBackground(String... message) {
       this.message = message[0];
       this.out =  service.getOut();
       this.in = service.getIn();
       try {
          this.out.writeBytes(this.message + "\n");
          this.out.flush();
       } catch (IOException e) {

           e.printStackTrace();
       }

       response = readLine(this.in);

       return response;
   }
```

I really don't know why it is not working, maybe the asynctask readLine reads the response first and then when my thread reads it, the DataInputStream is empty and it freezes.

Anyway, thanks for your help !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `(in.available() > 0){` evaluates to `false` you are wasting a whole CPU-core, if you are running on a single-core device your device would freeze.

To mitigate this start with `Thread.sleep` and advance into a `BlockingQueue` http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html

In addition you are accessing your service from two threads, I hope it's thread safe.

```
while(true){
  try {
    if (in.available() > 0) {                            
      msg = in.readLine();
      msg_parts = msg.split(" ");                         
      if (msg_parts[0].equals("CONNECTION")){
        Log.d("SocketService", "Broadcasting message");
        Intent intent = new Intent("ask.connection");
        intent.putExtra("nickname", msg_parts[1]);
        sendBroadcast(intent);
      }
    } else {
      Thread.sleep(100); // Or any sufficient delay.
    }
  } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: The check isn't needed at all, `BufferedReader.readLine()` (I believe this is what OP is using) is going to block anyway.